# how to integrate best-in-place with bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-datepicker, best-in-place

Everything is working fine with best-in-place but when I try to update a date with rails bootstrap-datepicker it is not working in fact when I click to select a date from calender best-in-place closed editable mode let me share some code.

```
<%= best_in_place da, :activity_date, :type=>:date, id: "date_input" %>
```

and script for datepicker is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#date_input').datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

How can Integrate best-in-place with bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: did you get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your jQuery selector:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#date_input>').datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

It should be `'#date_input'` and not `'#date_input>'`. Try to give more details of the error.